# Find the equation of the intersection of two tangent planes

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric, plane-geometry, tangent-line

I have two tangent planes that I've worked out from a previous part of this question:

$(1): 2x-2y+z=-2$

$(2): -8x+2y+4z=18$

I want to find the parametric equation for the intersection of these two tangent planes at the point $(-1,1,2)$ (I don't think the point is necessary anymore, I used this point to find the tangent planes previously).

Here's what I've done:

First I decided to re-write both equations with $y$ as the subject so I had:

$(1): y = x+\frac{1}2 z+1$

$(2): y = 9+4x-2z$

Since I had both equations equal to $y$ I made them equal to each other:$(3):$ $9+4x-2z=x+\frac{1}2 z+1$

From here I tried to find $z$ and $y$ in terms of $x$ so that I could set $x$ to be the parameter $t$, and then I would have $z$ and $y$ equal to some form of this parameter $t$ as well, however, along the way I think I've made a mistake or two that have led me to the incorrect answer, here's what I did:

First I tried to make $z$ the subject in equation $(3)$:
$8+3x-\frac{5}2z = 0$ => $z=\frac{16}5 + \frac{6}5 x$ (This doesn't seem quite right to me, other examples I've done very rarely have terms equal to fractions)

Then I took equation $(1)$ and since I had $z$, I substituted it in: $2x-2y+\frac{16}5 +\frac{6}5 x = -2$ => $y=\frac{16}{10} x +\frac{26}{10}$

From here I would set $x = $ the parameter $t$ and then re-write my equations of $z$ and $y$ to be in terms of $t$ and not $x$ then I would have my answer but the parametric equation is not correct.

I have access to the answer sheet and the answer provided is:$(-1,1,2) + (-10,-16,-12)t$ which is far from what I would get from my equations for $x,y,z$.

If someone could show me where I went wrong or if there is a better method to use it would really help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your work appears correct; when $x=-1$, the point is $(-1,1,2)$

Comment: Then I guess I'm just not sure how to get my answer in that form, my parametric equations would look something like: $x=t$, $y=\frac{16}{10} t + \frac{26}{10}$ and $z=\frac{16}{5} +\frac{6}{5} t$, I'm really not sure these are correct.

Comment: Wait, I'm so blind. If I just multiply all my $t$ values by $10$ I get the correct answer...

Comment: But am I allowed to just multiply by $10$? Also, do I just ignore the non-$t$ terms in the equations for $z,y$?

Comment: There's more that one way to parameterize a line.  You could write $P+tV$ where $P$ is a point on the line and $V$ a direction vector, or you could write $tP+(1-t)Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are two points on the line.  In either of those forms, there are many choices, of course.

Comment: Replace $t$ with $-1-10s$ since t is just a parameter. Your original form is fine though, there are lots of equivalent ways to write down a line

Comment: To see the equivalence, write $(x,y,z)$ as  a vector and then put it in the form $P+tV$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, there is no unique parametric representation of a line. In fact, there's infinitely many because you can take *any point* $P$ on the line and *any direction vector* $V$ (any non-zero multiple of any given direction vector, is still a direction vector of the line) to form $P+tV$.

You can look at your question as a system of two (linear) equations in three unknowns and solve it with any method you like. The solution, written parametrically, will take the form of the parametric equation of a line - the line of intersection.

> (...) or if there is a better method to use it would really help.

One fast way to derive a *direction vector* of that line, since you already had a point $P$, is by using the **cross** (or vector) **product**. You may know that you can simply read normal vectors of the given planes since $(a,b,c)$ is a normal vector of a plane given by $ax+by+c+d=0$, so here:

> $(1): 2x-2y+z=-2$
>
> $(2): -8x+2y+4z=18$

normal vectors of the two planes are $(2,-2,1)$ and $(-8,2,4)$ respectively. The (line of) intersection of the two planes has to be *perpendicular* to both planes, so its direction (vector) has to be perpendicular to both normal vectors. This is precisely what the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) produces and you can verify that:
$$(2,-2,1) \times (-8,2,4) = (-10,-16,-12)$$
It can be good practice to simplify the direction vector, definitely if there are follow-up questions which would require further calculations with this result (e.g. divide by $-2$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the method you've shown on how to quickly get the derivative is the method I think I remember my lecturer using to answer this question previously but it was a long time ago so I forgot it. Thanks for the quick reply and the clarification

Comment: This cross product method only applies in 3 dimensions. More generally, your approach is used though using matrix row reduction for efficiency.

Comment: I have just one more question, in your answer you showed a way to quickly find the intersection since it is perpendicular (by using the cross product), In a later part of this question I have to find a point where the $(1)$ is parallel to a given plane (different to the one in this question). I'm just wondering if there's a quick way to find the point where the two are parallel or if a longer method is required. If you want I  can create a new post and link it here so you can see what I mean.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what the (new) question is. With "(1)", are you referring to the first plane? What about the line of intersection? Perhaps it's better to post a new question or if it's something small, add it to this question.

Comment: I'll make a new question and link it here, give me a minute

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4222218/928623